# Close Menu by clicking off menu & ESC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a basic menu system for my website.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/k46bm0Lb/

How do I edit my code to allow the menu to close when I **a)** hit ESC on my keyboard & **b)** click anywhere on the page that isn't the menu.

Code:

```js
 /*!
  * classie - class helper functions
  * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
  * 
  * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
  * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
  * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
  * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
  */

 /*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
 /*global define: false */

 ( function( window ) {

 'use strict';

 // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

 function classReg( className ) {
   return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
 }

 // classList support for class management
 // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
 var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

 if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
   hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
     return elem.classList.contains( c );
   };
   addClass = function( elem, c ) {
     elem.classList.add( c );
   };
   removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
     elem.classList.remove( c );
   };
 }
 else {
   hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
     return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
   };
   addClass = function( elem, c ) {
     if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
       elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
     }
   };
   removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
     elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
   };
 }

 function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
   var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
   fn( elem, c );
 }

 var classie = {
   // full names
   hasClass: hasClass,
   addClass: addClass,
   removeClass: removeClass,
   toggleClass: toggleClass,
   // short names
   has: hasClass,
   add: addClass,
   remove: removeClass,
   toggle: toggleClass
 };

 // transport
 if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
   // AMD
   define( classie );
 } else {
   // browser global
   window.classie = classie;
 }

 })( window );









 /**
  * main.js
  * http://www.codrops.com
  *
  * Licensed under the MIT license.
  * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  * 
  * Copyright 2014, Codrops
  * http://www.codrops.com
  */
 (function() {

  var bodyEl = document.body,
   content = document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' ),
   openbtn = document.getElementById( 'open-button' ),
   closebtn = document.getElementById( 'close-button' ),
   isOpen = false;

  function init() {
   initEvents();
  }

  function initEvents() {
   openbtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
   if( closebtn ) {
    closebtn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleMenu );
   }

   // close the menu element if the target itÂ´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
   content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if( isOpen && target !== openbtn ) {
     toggleMenu();
    }
   } );
  }

  function toggleMenu() {
   if( isOpen ) {
    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
   }
   else {
    classie.add( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
   }
   isOpen = !isOpen;
  }

  init();

 })();
```

```css
  /************Reset**************/
  *,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

  html, body, div, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, ol, ul, li, form, fieldset, legend, label, table, header, footer, nav, section { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
  } 
  ol, ul { 
   list-style: none; 
  }
  header, footer, nav, section, article, hgroup, figure {
   display: block; 
  }
  legend {
   display: none;
  }
  /************End Reset**************/

  /************Global**************/
  body { 
   font: 100%/1.5 'Gill Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Calibri', 'Lucida Grande', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; 
   color: #000;
   background: #fff; 
   text-align: left;
  }
  a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000;
  }
  a:hover, a:focus {
   color: #000;
  }
  img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
  }
  h1 {
   font: normal 14px/1em 'Gill Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Calibri', 'Lucida Grande', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #fff;
   text-transform:lowercase;
  }
  h2 {
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: normal;
   margin: 0;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  }
  h3 {
   margin: 0;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  }
  p {
   margin: 0 0 1em;
  }
  label {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #fff;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   -o-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0.5em;
   border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
   border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
   padding: 0.4em 0.5em;
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   height: 2.4em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  input,textarea {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1em;
   background: #fff;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   -o-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   border-left: 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0.5em;
   border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
   padding: 0.25em 0.6em;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   height: 2.4em;
  }
  input[type=submit] {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  select {
   font-size: 1em;
   background: #fff;
   background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 95% 50% rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
   -o-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   border-left: 0;
   padding: 0.25em 0.6em;
   height: 2.4em;
   width: 49.5%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0.5em;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0.5em;
   border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
   border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
  }
  select:focus, input:focus {
   background-color: #fff;
   outline: none;
  }
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #999;
  }
  :-moz-placeholder {
     color: #999;
  }
  /************End Global**************/








  /************Custom**************/
  footer {
   padding:10px;
   /*background:#fff;*/
  }

  header {
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   padding:10px;
  }

  /* Navigation Menu - Background */
  .navigation {
    /* critical sizing and position styles */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow:scroll;
    
    /* non-critical appearance styles */
    list-style: none;
    background:#fff;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-size:14px;
  }

  /* Navigation Menu - List items */
  .nav-item {
    /* non-critical appearance styles */
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em;
  }

  .nav-item a {
    /* non-critical appearance styles */
    display: block;
    padding-bottom:0;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav-item a:hover {
    color: #000;
  }

  .date {
   display:block;
  }

  /* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
  .site-wrap {
    /* Critical position and size styles */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: white; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    
    /* non-critical apperance styles */
    padding: 20px;
  }

  /* Nav Trigger */
  .nav-trigger {
    /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    /* critical positioning styles */
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px; top: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    
    /* non-critical apperance styles */
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
    background-size: contain;
  }

  /* Make the Magic Happen */
  .nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
    transition: left 0.2s;
  }

  .nav-trigger:checked + label {
    left: 215px;
  }

  .nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap,.nav-trigger:checked ~ footer {
    left: 200px;
  }

  body {
   /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  /* Additional non-critical styles */

  h1, h3, p {
    max-width: 600px;
    /*margin: 0 auto 1em;*/
  }

  code {
   padding: 2px;
   background: #ddd;
  }



  a.request {
   font-size: 14px;
   padding-top:0;
  }

  footer p {
   font-size:0.7em;
   line-height:1.2em;
  }

  footer i.fa {
   font-size:1.3em;
   float:left;
   margin-right:10px;
  }



































.menu-wrap a {
  color: #b8b7ad;
}

.menu-wrap a:hover,
.menu-wrap a:focus {
  color: #c94e50;
}

.content-wrap {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background: #b4bad2;
}

.content::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0s 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

/* Menu Button */
.menu-button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.25em;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 2.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  right: 0.5em;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(#373a47 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #373a47 40%, #373a47 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #373a47 80%);
  content: '';
}

.menu-button:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-button {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 1em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.close-button::before,
.close-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #bdc3c7;
}

.close-button::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close-button::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Menu */
.menu-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #373a47;
  padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.menu, 
.icon-list {
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.icon-list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8em;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,500px,0);
}

.icon-list,
.icon-list a {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0s 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,1000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,1500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,2000px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,2500px,0);
}

.icon-list a:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,3000px,0);
}

.icon-list a span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Shown menu */
.show-menu .menu-wrap {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.show-menu .icon-list,
.show-menu .icon-list a {
}

.show-menu .icon-list a {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.9s;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
}

.show-menu .content::before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-wrap">
  <nav class="menu">
   <ul class="navigation">
         <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="http://localhost:8888/index.php/news/2015/new-entry-test">New Entry Test</a>
     </li>
       </ul>
  </nav>
  <i class="close-button fa fa-chevron-left" id="close-button"></i>
 </div>
 <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>

 <div class="site-wrap">
        <p>hello</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement the `Esc`

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { // Esc keycode
            //your code to hide the menu 
        }
    });
```

To hide when the user click out(for the phone):

```
$('.site-wrap').on('click', function(e){
  if($('body').hasClass('show-menu')){
      toggleMenu();
   } 
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So something like `$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { // Esc keycode
            toggleMenu();
        }
    });`? http://jsfiddle.net/k46bm0Lb/4/

Comment: yep.. take a look, it's working http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/k46bm0Lb/7/ @michaelmcgurk

Comment: Fantastic!! And is it possible to code it so you click off the menu & the menu disappears?

Comment: yep, let me take a look :)

Comment: I'm changing some of your code.. because I'm getting some errors, so give me some minuts. :)

Comment: here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/k46bm0Lb/9/ take a look. Hope it's help :) give me a positive point if it's working or let me know if something doesnt work properly. @michaelmcgurk

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Many, many thanks for your persistence too!!! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if (isOpen) {
        classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
        isOpen = false;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        if (isOpen) {
            classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
            isOpen = !isOpen;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried that here: http://jsfiddle.net/k46bm0Lb/5/ and unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` on this line `content.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {`

Comment: let me see, it returns null for this `document.querySelector( '.content-wrap' )`, why don't you use jQuery instead?

Comment: There's no class named '.content-wrap' in your html, can you please re-check your html code?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the "click anywhere else to close" method in my previous test project in it's own vanilla js gallery here : http://my-x-perience.at/?page=shop&device=1&category=3&show=11#detailingamescreenshots

Basically what I did is, create an overlay (can be transparent as well) above the whole content whenever you open a "modal"box and put an eventlistener on that overlay to close anything you want.

Source here : http://my-x-perience.at/scripts/detailpage.js

snippet:

```
lightboxBg.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    lightbox.style.display = "none";
    lightboxBg.style.display = "none";
    var left = document.querySelector('#screen-lightbox > div > .fa-arrow-circle-o-left');
    var right = document.querySelector('#screen-lightbox > div > .fa-arrow-circle-o-right');
    lightboxInnerWrapper.removeChild(left);
    lightboxInnerWrapper.removeChild(right);
});
```